# javaFX не хочет ставить иконку на приложение

Tags: java, javafx, icon

Я хочу поставить свою иконку на приложение, но когда я её ставлю, при компиляции приложения выдаёт ошибку, подскажите пожалуйста, что не так, вот код:[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Похоже, что он пытается забрать картинку из файловой системы из папки с программой,  а не из ресурсной.

Answer (score 0):

new Image("file:src/.../icon.png")

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]